# Is it faster to send a picture message through 2G or Wi-Fi?

Tags: wi-fi, mms, 2g

I have a LG Mytouch android smartphone.
I need to send a picture out tonight!

Comment: Wifi obviously. 54Mbit broadband versus 220 kbit/s max via 2G.

Comment: @ce4 Wrong concept. What if Wi-Fi is broadcasting 2G...

Answer (score 2):

It differs with your connection quality, in normal situations Wi-Fi is faster.

Wi-Fi mostly not usable for MMS, so you need to use e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of internet is available on Wi-Fi network. A Wi-Fi hotspot can broadcast internet provided by 1G, 2G, 2.5G, 3G, 3.5G, 4G, DSL, ADSL, ADSL2, T1 etc. So, the comparison is meaningless unless you know the back-end connection. If you know the back-end connection, the question shouldn't exist.

Comment: You are aware that [WiFi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) usually refers to the technology behind IEEE 802.11 and not any kind of wireless communication technology?

Comment: @Flow Hold on a second.. If question is comparing 2G with Wi-Fi, its direct meaning is that questioner wants to send picture over internet, not inside Wi-Fi network. And, you must know Wi-Fi can just share internet connections of other technologies. It doesn't provide native internet. You have misconceptions.

Comment: @Flow With Android's MobileAP, you can share 2G connection over Wi-Fi. If questioner has plugged his device with this Wi-Fi, do you think, it'd be faster than his native 2G?

Comment: "It can broadcast 1G, 2G, 2.5G, 3G, 3.5G, 4G, DSL, ADSL, ADSL2, T1" sounds like the WiFi AP is using those technologies, when you really want to say "The WiFi AP can be connected to the internet over one of those technologies."

Comment: @Flow Alright. Re-phrased that sentence...